# Usercontrol Panel visibility

Tags: winforms, user-controls

This is my first post.
I have created a Usercontrol in my existing windows project and which has two panel, Now I have used this usercontrol into my new form.

When I am trying to hide using PrintExporttoexcelpanel.Visible = false; it give me an error "The name PrintExporttoexcelpanel" does not exist i current contest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution by using this.myControl1.btnPrint.Visible = false; I can hide the button of my usercontrol only we need to change access modifier for "btnPrint" from public to private or protected internal.